# Return all account holdings in transaction summary even when specific holdings are not affected

Tags: sql

Apologies in advance as I am having trouble phrasing the issue I am dealing with, but...

I am trying to build a report that gives a snapshot of an account post-transaction.  Each account may have multiple items in it and each transaction may only affect a limited number of items on the master account.

```
*ITEM*       *Total Quantity*      *Quantity Sold*
 apples          100,000                5,000  
 oranges         250,000
 cherries        175,000                25,000
```

I want my table to return all of the items in column A even if there was no transaction in the order in Column C.  What I have so far looks like:

```
SELECT act.ITEM, act.TotalQuantity, ord.QuantitySold
FROM Accounts AS act
JOIN Orders AS ord ON ord.ITEM = act.ITEM
```

In the above query, the second row of results is getting dropped because there was not a portion of the order that affected the item.  How can I ensure that the entirety of column A remains intact?

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN

```
   SELECT act.ITEM, act.TotalQuantity, 
        IsNull(ord.QuantitySold,0) as QuantitySold
    FROM Accounts AS act
    JOIN Orders AS ord ON ord.ITEM = act.ITEM
```